# Change color of status bar in particular fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my android app there is one MainActivity and a lot of fragments.
In HomeFragment I need to have a status bar with color purple but in other white.
App has

```
style name="AppStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"
```

For MainActivity I use

```
<style name="Theme.ActivityStatusBarPurple" parent="AppStyle">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_purple</item>
</style>
```

In `onCreateView` of HomeFragment I use

```
requireActivity().window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

In `onDestroyView` of HomeFragment I use

```
requireActivity().window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

Partially I've got desirable result: status bar has purple color but there two side effects:
my layout overlap navigation bar at bottom and a purple color is visible in other fragments status bar.

How to overlap only status bar not changing a navigation bar and how to keep white color for other fragments status bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very simple solution. In every fragment's `onCreateView` I set this line:

```
requireActivity().window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), R.color.my_color)
```

No need to change a theme